# How to create python test script to access services hosted in GAE which require login

Tags: python, google-app-engine

buddies

One of my GAE restful service needs login with admin account. And I'm writing an automation script in python for testing this service. The script simply do a HTTP POST and then check the returned response. The difficult part for me is how to authenticate the test script as an admin user.

I created an admin account for testing purpose. But I'm not sure how to use that account in my test script. Is there a way that my test script can use oath2 or other approach to authenticate itself as a test admin account?

Comment: have you tried this? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/adminusers

Comment: Hi, @Faisal, thanks for your comments. It's not a problem to create an admin account. The major problem for me is that I don't even know how to authenticate the test script as a normal user. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think this might be what you are looking for, client libraries to authenticate and yeah I believe appengine now recommends using the oauth2 for any kind of authentication:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#libraries

Then you get an auth token where you pass in headers on your restful request like:

```
# Your authenticated request
Authorization: Bearer TokenHere
```

Then in your handler you get it like:

```
try:
    user = oauth.get_current_user('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo')
except NotAllowedError:
    user = None

# then from the first link you should be able to access if
user.is_current_user_admin()
```

This is how I authenticate on android, but I only do this once and store it in session and just enable cookie jar on the httpclient.